# React UseEffect and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm displaying 9 cards on my home page. each card contains an Image,link and description.

everytime I'm clicking on home, page is being loaded after few seconds. to show information on those cards I'm using an API call in useEffect.

Question is: when I'm clicking on Home button, is it calling that API again n again ?
if yes, can we stop that calling ? like store all information at a place and then use it again ??

for that purpose, I guess we use Redux, right?

I just need some light on this scenario.

## thanks,

I'm trying to create a personal blogging website, where I'll be putting local news snippet.

## as I'm learning, trying to implement this project using React.js.

Comment: Please provide problematic code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.